# Como modificar valores de TextInput com Formik?

Tags: react-native

Minha situação é a seguinte: o usuário informa um CEP e o aplicativo consulta uma API, retornando os dados que irei setar nos demais campos como `city`, `state` etc.

Para isso preciso alterar a propriedade `value` dos demais `TextInput` e recuperá-las ao submeter o `form`, mas não sei como fazê-lo.

```
<Formik                initialValues={{
                            name: "",
                            birthDate: null,
                            cpf: "",
                            cep: "",
                            city: "",
                            neighborhood: "",
                            complement: "",
                            state: "",
                            address: "",
                            numeberAddress: ""
                        }}
                        validationSchema={FormSchema}
                        onSubmit={onSubmit}
                    >
                        {({ touched, values, errors, handleChange, handleSubmit, setFieldValue }) => (
                            <View >
                                <Input valueInput={values.cep}
                                    onChangeText={(value) => { consultCep(value, setFieldValue) }}
                                    keyboardType="numeric"
                                    placeholder="Informe o CEP"
                                    mask="99999-999"
                                    labelInput="CEP"
                                    iconInput="location-arrow"
                                    required={true}
                                />
                                {errors.cep && touched.cep && <HelperText type="error"> {errors.cep}</HelperText>}

                                <Input valueInput={values.city}
                                    onChangeText={handleChange('city')}
                                    placeholder="Informe sua cidade"
                                    labelInput="CIDADE"
                                    iconInput="city"
                                    required={true}
                                />
                                {errors.city && touched.city && <HelperText type="error"> {errors.city}</HelperText>}
```

Comment: Formik é de qual pacote no repositorios npm?

Comment: Eu segui a documentação https://formik.org/docs/overview estou usando o Formik com o yup para validar os campos.

Comment: mas, esse `<Input>` é do ReactNative correto? Não cole imagem coloque o código e todo o código

Comment: <Imput> é um component criei para TextInput, estou tentando alterar os dados com a metodo setFieldValue mas sem sucesso.

Comment: é pela função `setFieldValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se o nome das props que recebem os valores do component estão corretos e você também pode declarar o Formik como uma const para ter acesso as suas funções em toda a página, por exemplo:

```
const { touched, values, errors, handleChange, handleSubmit, setFieldValue } = useFormik({
   Propriedades do seu Formik aqui...
})
```